# How do I properly mount a socket into a running container on MacOS?

Tags: docker, sockets

I opened a [more specific post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67393748/npgsql-cant-connect-to-a-unix-socket-from-inside-container) about connecting to Postgres over a Unix socket in a container.

But the issue is not Postgres specific. I am not able to connect to a Unix socket on my host from a container.

First I open a socket connection on my host. This is the gcp cloudsql proxy process:

```
sudo ~/cloud_sql_proxy \
  -enable_iam_login \
  -dir=/var/run/cloudsql \
  -instances=myproject:region:instance
```

Finding the socket the process creates:

```
netstat -u | grep instance
bcbc9fce31bfedb3 stream      0      0 bcbc9fce45af6cdb                0                0                0 /var/run/cloudsql/myproject:region:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I confirm the connection is accessible on my host with socat:

```
socat - UNIX-CONNECT:'/var/run/cloudsql/myproject\:region\:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432'
```

The connection is opened and the proxy process dumps logs to stdout showing the connection was established:

```
2021/11/17 13:11:17 New connection for "myproject:region:instance"
```

Now I can also connect with psql as well without issue, but socat is the lowest common denominator and I can prove the connection is accessible on my host machine. What I need to do now is run a container and connect to this socket on my host.

Doing a `docker run` mounting in the socket fails with an error:

```
docker run \
    -v /var/run/cloudsql:/var/run/cloudsql \
    --entrypoint /bin/bash \
    "postgres:latest" \
    -c ' \
        /usr/bin/apt update -y && \
        /usr/bin/apt install socat -y && \
        /usr/bin/socat - UNIX-CONNECT:"/var/run/cloudsql/myproject\:region\:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432"'

socat[1] E connect(5, AF=1 "/var/run/cloudsql/myproject:region:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432", 80): Connection refused
```

I see no output at all from the socket process when getting this error - indicating it's not even touching it.

I tried mounting the socket specifically but get an error from Docker:

```
docker run \
    -v '/var/run/cloudsql/myproject:region:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432':'/var/run/cloudsql/myproject:region:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432' \
    --entrypoint /bin/bash \
    "postgres:latest" \
    -c ' \
        /usr/bin/apt update -y && \
        /usr/bin/apt install socat -y && \
        /usr/bin/socat - UNIX-CONNECT:"/var/run/cloudsql/myproject\:region\:instance/.s.PGSQL.5432"'

docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification
```

I also tried creating a socket on the host:

```
 socat UNIX-LISTEN:'/var/run/cloudsql/test.sock' -
```

Connecting to that inside a container with `socat - UNIX-CONNECT` returns the same error (but can connect on the host).

### Edit

It looks like this is an issue with Docker on Mac: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/483

Is it possible to use the SSH_AUTH_SOCK workaround for my use case?

Comment: I suspect, since Docker on MacOS runs a hidden Linux VM, you can't connect to a host Unix socket, even if you successfully bind-mount the socket file's directory; it's not "on the same system".